# uniqueness validation in update record in phalcon

Tags: php, api, validation, phalcon

i used phalcon framework to build rest api .. i was built all CRUD functions but when using update i can't update record because validation failed because email is unique .. i want to update this record with skip the unique validation ..
this is my validation :

```
class UpdateUserValidation extends Validation
{
public function initialize()
{

$this->add(
        'email', 
        new Uniqueness([
        "model"   => new Users,
            "message" => ": email already exist",
        ]));
}}
```

and this is my function in controller :

```
public function updateAction($id)
    {
$validation = new UpdateUserValidation;
        $messages = $validation->validate($_POST);
if (count($messages) > 0 ) {
            $all_errors = array();
             foreach ($messages as $message) {
        array_push($all_errors, $message->getMessage());
              
             }

$this->response->setStatusCode(422,'Validation Error');
    $this->response->setJsonContent(array('Message' => $all_errors));
        return $this->response; 
}
```

any help please

> Phalcon DevTools (3.4.0)
>
> PHP 7.1

Comment: Are the users allowed to change their e-mail when updating?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really well documented, but if you use the current row instance (model) for the validation, that record will be ignored.

```php
// get record
    $user = Users::findFirst([
        'email = :email:',
        'bind' => [
            'email' => 'info@test.com',
        ],
    ]);

// validation
    $this->add('email', new Uniqueness([
        'model'   => $user,
        'message' => ':email already exist',
    ]));

    $messages = $this->validate([
        'email' => 'info@test.com',
    ]);
    // success, because added current record

    $messages = $this->validate([
        'email' => 'existing@email.com',
    ]);
    // fails, a record with this email already exists

// save
    if(!$messages) {
        $user->save([
            'email'  => 'info@test.com',
        ]);
    }
```